# Javascript Regex to match and replace tag brackets if tag is closed

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am copying html to a content editable on keyup and I want the html to be turned into html tags.

The contenteditable creates entities.

I figured I would use Javascript replace fn and it worked until now.

This is what I have:

```
 replace(/&lt;(\w+)&gt;(.*)&lt;\/\1&gt;/gi,'<$1>$2</$1>')
```

The problem arises if you put for e.g. a `<b></b>` inside a `<p></p>`. Of course since the content is copied all the time, it will only replace the p tag and leave the brackets of the b tag in entities. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: you can't do this with regex; html is a semantic language. You need to create (or find) a DOM parser script

Comment: But why, it works this far. I just need to also replace the entities inside the given tag. Then it would work fine. The proble is just that $2 holds entities which are not replaced.

Comment: regex alone cannot do this, *regular* expressions means that the "rules" follow a pattern. html is a semantic language, which follows a different set of rules.  Some tags do not have a closing tag counterpart.  Also, they can be nested infinitely. They can be interpreted multiple ways.  Regex alone cannot parse it 100% because you need loops and conditions thrown into the mix. It's like trying to break down a sentence in spanish by using the rules of english.